# List comprehension for the folder structure code

Tags: python

I have following string...
str = 'a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4'
I want output
1\2\3\4

```
        folderlist = str.split('&')
        folderpath =''
        for folder in folderlist:
            folderpath = folderpath + folder.split("=")[1] + '\\'
        print(folderpath)
```

Any idea, how can I write this in the list comprehension ?

Comment: Why do you want to write it as a list comprehension? For starters, it *doesn't create a list*.  But generally, here, you want to create a list, then `''.join` it at the end.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a query string here? Because you should use `urllib.parse.parse_qs`

Comment: Yes, I am doing that only. Is there any recommendation. I want to create the path of my folder based on the query string.

Comment: Use `urllib.parse.parse_qs` or probably `urllib.parse.parse_qsl` here

Comment: In which case, this becomes: `'\\'.join([v for _,v in url_parse.parse_qsl(qs)])`

Comment: Avoid using `str` as the name of your variable. It's a reserved term, a function to create new strings from a given object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
path = "a=C&b=Users&c=Name&d=folder"

'\\'.join([a.split('=')[1] for a in path.split('&')])
```

O/P:

```
'C\\Users\\Name\\folder'
```

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use a variable with the name `str` because that's an existing function and will overwrite it.

The syntax for basic list comprehension is: `[expression for variable in iterable]`.  So these two pieces of code are (basically) the same loop:

```py
l = []
for num in [1, 2, 3]:
    l.append(num + 1)
```

and

```py
l = [num + 1 for num in [1, 2, 3]]
```

To accomplish what you want, do this:

```py
path = "a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4"

folderpath = "".join([folder.split("=")[1] + "\\" for folder in path.split("&")])

print(folderpath)
#prints:
#1\2\3\4\
```

Comment: If you don't want the trailing `"\\"`, change the middle line to `folderpath = "\\".join([folder.split("=")[1] for folder in path.split("&")])`.

Comment: I changed the example to better fit the purpose of list comprehensions.